# MySQL error - “You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."posts (`id`, `user`, `name`, `link`, `content`, `date`, `private`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$name', '$link', '$content', '$date', '$private', '$pass');";
    $mysqli->query($query) OR $status = 'Oprostite, pri dodajanju je prišlo do težave.';
    $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
    foreach ($_POST['categories'] as $category) {
        $categoryQuery.="INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('".$category."','".$id."');";
    }
    $mysqli->query($categoryQuery) OR $status = $mysqli->error;
}
echo $status;
```

My variable $_POST is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => ((((((((((
    [description] => ))))))
    [keywords] => 
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [private] => 0
    [password] => 
    [date] => 0
    [datetime] => 
    [add] => Dodaj
)
```

If I print the query and run it in phpMyAdmin there is no problem, otherwise it will display an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO fc_category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('2','116');INSERT' at line 1

Query is:

```
INSERT INTO fc_category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('1','116');
INSERT INTO fc_category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('2','116');
INSERT INTO fc_category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('3','116');
```

Comment: Seems like you can only pass one INSERT at the time.

Comment: how can customize the code that will work

Comment: You just need to change your loop code to this: `foreach ($_POST['categories'] as $category) {
        $categoryQuery ="INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) VALUES ('".$category."','".$id."');"; $mysqli->query($categoryQuery);`
    }

Comment: You cannot run more than one query statement in a single `query()` call, as a basic defense mechanism against ONE form of [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com), which your code is utterly vulnerable to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can only pass the one `INSERT` then why not do it like this;

```
INSERT INTO fc_category_posts (`categoryID`, `postID`) 
VALUES ('1','116'),('2','116'),('3','116');
```

Saves you running multiple `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: Would be simpler to just move the query inside the loop in this case, rather than rewriting code to make this work

Comment: Could be, I'm a simple SQL guy so looked for the answer that way.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply move the execution of the query inside the loop

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."posts 
                   (`id`, `user`, `name`, `link`, `content`, `date`, 
                    `private`, `password`) 
               VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$name', '$link', '$content', '$date', 
                       '$private', '$pass');";

    $mysqli->query($query) OR $status = 'Oprostite, pri dodajanju je prišlo do težave.';
    $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
    foreach ($_POST['categories'] as $category) {

        //Note I have chnages `.=` to `=` in this statement
        $categoryQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."category_posts 
                                   (`categoryID`, `postID`) 
                            VALUES ('$category','$id');";

        $mysqli->query($categoryQuery) OR $status = $mysqli->error;
    }

}
echo $status;
```

> However Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
>
> In this senario it would also be useful for you to consider running these inside a transaction so that if one insert fails you wont leave the darabase in a mess [The manual for mysqli::begin_transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)